# Finding constant from probability mass function

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a **discrete** random variable with probability distribution (probability mass function),

$P(x) = c(\frac{1}{3})^x, x = 0,1,2,...$

---

a) Find $c$ such that $P(x)$ is a legitimate PDF.

b) Find the CDF of $X$, $F(x), x ∈ \{0,1,2,...\}$

---

b) Here I was thinking of using this formula:

$\sum_{k = 1}^x P(k)$

So,

$\sum_{k = 0}^x c(\frac{1}{3})^k = \sum_{k = 1}^x c(\frac{1}{3})^{x - 1}$

$= c\frac{(1 - \frac{1}{3}^x)}{1 - \frac{1}{3}}$

Does it even make sense?

I'm stuck on a)

Answer (score 1):

To find $c$ we must have
$$
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}P(x)=1\quad\Longrightarrow \quad\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}c\left(\frac 13\right)^x=c\frac32=1\quad\Longrightarrow \quad c=\frac23
$$

For b) we have

$$
F(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{x}P(x)=\frac23\sum_{k=0}^{x}\left(\frac 13\right)^k=1-\frac{1}{3^{x+1}}\qquad \text{for}\;x=0,1,2,\ldots
$$
and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: How do you go from $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}c\left(\frac 13\right)^x$ to $c\frac32$?

Comment: This is a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html): $\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k=\frac{1}{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$

Comment: I know that. I'm just a little confused as to how to plug in infinity

Comment: For $r=\frac 13$ you have $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c(1/3)^k=c\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(1/3)^k=\frac{c}{1-\frac 13}=\frac{c}{\frac 23}=1$ and then $c=\frac 23$.

Comment: The partial sum is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^k=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ and taking the limit for $n\to\infty$ with $|r|<1$, $r^{n+1}\to 0$ and then $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}r^k=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}=\frac{1}{1-r}\qquad |r|<1$$

Comment: So I can write the CDF as $F(x) = \begin{cases} {1-\frac{1}{3^{x+1}}} & \text{$x \geq 0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$?

Comment: Yes you can! exactly